# Computer hangs for about ~20 minutes on "Starting windows" screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, reboot

My girlfriend has a Samsung RF-711-S02 Laptop, I recently had some software issues with her laptop that lead me to reformat it for her.   Ever since reformatting the computer will hang for quite a while on boot (~20 - ~30 minutes) and then boot / run entirely normally.

Windows 7 Score index places her hard disk at 5.9, all I/O on the hard disk seems to be just about normal.   I've ordered a replacement drive already, but if it's not the hard drive what else could it be?  I can't see it being the processor since if that was messed up it would show once in windows.  Same goes for the video card (She's gamed on it since).   Ram checks out fine as well.

Is there any kind of hard disk tool I can use

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not the hard drive.  Did you check the event log?  Long boot times like that almost sound like services that are failing.  Are you sure you have all the proper drivers for the hardware?

Comment: Positive, it actually happened before I installed any device drivers (first boot from Windows 7 setup (fresh format)) on the machine at all.  It's a 2.0ghz quad core... I feel like loading windows really only takes Hard drive / processor and a vga driver to display the splash animation, right?